# Visual Studio webtest to create profiles

Tags: visual-studio-2015, web-testing, guidewire

Good morning,

I've done a lot of research on this but I honestly haven't found anything that can help me so i am hoping the kindness of everyone here might be able to help.

I work for an insurance company and we are attempting to use Visual Studio's web recorder to automate our process for testing the creation of claims.  The process is an employee with key in the information to produce the claim, then we will set dynamic parameters for the fields, and theoretically we run the wettest to create a new claim.  However the problem is when we go to re-run the web-test we get 200's all the way down but no new claim is created. We had an issue with CSRF tokens which we addressed with a plugin, and if I look at the code generated by teh webtest I am not seeing anything that would be like "HEY this is a dynamic value".    Are we trying to use Visual's studios webtest in the wrong way or is there something we are missing that we need to update.  We are currently using this against the GuideWire 9 environment if that means anything to anyone.

-Thank you

Comment: There is too little detail in your question to give and answer. Perhaps these answers to other questions will help: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943677/web-performance-testing-with-datasource-in-vs-2012/16944240#16944240 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25647166/web-performance-test-signalr-unrecognized-user-identity/25675028#25675028 .

Comment: You could perhaps look at http://madcow.4impact.net.au also. Disclaimer: I worked on the product and have used it for guidewire testing